# Duplicate entries in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I am facing a strange problem in Hibernate. Operating in a multithreaded env, when trying to insert into one of the tables, getting duplicate entries in table. Only the primary key is different, rest all other fields are getting exactly duplicate.

Using Hibernate + Oracle and using Spring - HibernateTemplate object.

Here's the relevant portion of my my BO class and below given code to save the object. Not using any transient fields.

Have checked other posts related to this, but none of them addresses the root cause of the problem. I don't want to introduce any constraints/unique indexes on db table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ADIRECIPIENTINTERACTION")
@Lazy(value = true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@GenericGenerator(name="recipientInteractionSeq", strategy = "native", parameters = 
{ @Parameter(name="sequence", value="SEQiRecipientInteractId")})
public class RecipientInteractionBO extends BusinessObject{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "recipientInteractionSeq", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="IRECIPIENTINTERACTIONID")     
    private long lId; ....
```

And here's the Code used to save the BO.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
RecipientInteractionBO recInt = (RecipientInteractionBO) objectPS
                    .getUniqueResult(detachedCriteria);
if (recInt == null) {
 recInt = new RecipientInteractionBO();
 ....
 hibernateTemplateObj.insertObject(recInt);
} else {
  ...
   hibernateTemplateObj.saveOrUpdate(recInt);
}
```

Please let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: Is the problem you are facing is only seen in multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Yes, that's only in multithreaded env.

Answer (score 1):

Check your data persistence code for possible race conditions for multiple threads. You are checking for the existence of the `RecipientInteractionBO` which is possibly querying from database. If two threads are running simultaneously, both check for it's existence, since for both it's not there both persist the new entity. You might need to use synchronization to make the process of checking and inserting/updating to be done only for one thread at a single time.

Comment: This BO directly corresponds to the User and there is no scenario where same user can come from two different threads. So, this can't be an issue.

Comment: What I meant to say is that let's say there are two thread t1 and t2. First thread t1 checks the existence in database. It doesn't find so it proceeds to persist a new one but before it can commit its changes thread t2 also checks and sees that the data does not exist and it also creates a new one hence two entities are persisted.

Comment: Yes, exactly so this is not the case with our code. No two threads are dealing with same user.

Comment: Then probably you might need to enable the hibernate debug log and have a look at the logs to understand more